# What are typical trigonometry textbooks in the 17 th century?

Tags: mathematics

I was wondering, what book did people use in the 17 th century to learn trigonometry as it was before ? Just general curiosity...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out, [Bartholomaeus Pitiscus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartholomaeus_Pitiscus) is known as the person who introduced the word trigonometry into the English language in the sense that we understand the word today. In 1595 he produced *Trigonometria: sive de solutione triangulorum tractatus brevis et perspicuus*, and this seminal work was, throughout the 17th century, translated into English several times.

A copy of the Latin original can be found at [e-rara](http://www.e-rara.ch/doi/10.3931/e-rara-4035), and here is another copy at [bsb](http://reader.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/fs1/object/display/bsb10164580_00005.html).

I know this book was translated to English a few times throughout the 17th century, but I can't manage to find a good download link at the moment.

Pitiscus' book was certainly not the only trigonometry book used in the 17th century, but it stands out as being a very important historical example, and one which I think deserves mention.

Comment: Ah ok, seems interesting. It would be good to see if there's an english version disponible online. Thank you again!

Comment: Yeah I know it's somewhere, we'll dig one up eventually no doubt. :)

Comment: I happen to know french also, so if there's a french one it would be fine.

Comment: It was also translated to French.

Comment: @Astroman I can see you speak French from the use of the non-english word "disponible" - you want "available" :)

Comment: oh... I was sure that "disponible" existed. Thank you for telling me!

Comment: @JackM: Just for the record, "disponible" is a valid word in the Spanish language, too...